# Shopify embed app developement in php redirection problem.

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I am making a embed shopify app in php, I am using this app skeleton

https://github.com/phpish/shopify_app-skeleton

I followed instruction and able to install app.

After app install I redirected to a page (Oauth.php) with message "App Successfully Installed!"

But I want to make a embed app so after some reserch I found that we can make an index.php with content below

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.init({
      apiKey: 'APP_KEY',
      shopOrigin: '<?php echo $_REQUEST['shop']?>',
      debug: false
    });
  </script>


</head>
<body>
  Content of embed app.
```

Now when I open app in shopify admin dashboard I can see it. 
But after adding index.html as above I am not able to install app again.

Can anyone please suggest advice what I am doing wrong and what is correct way to make shopify embed app in php.

Thanks again.

Comment: It is too difficult to answer this question for many reasons. One, you really show no code exhibiting problems, and two, the concept of embedded Apps is far too complex and indepth to debug from your simple "cannot install it again". You have to map out your strategy and show it off for people to help you. Without more context, and descriptions, it is impossible to give a one-line code fix or other suggestions you may seek.